# Обратные ссылки в путях файлов Grunt

Tags: javascript, grunt

Здравствуйте.
Возникло затруднение в обработке путей в Grunt, а именно задачу **concat**: как передать что-то из найденных путей в значение целевого пути?
Есть примерно такая структура проекта:

```
src
-js
--Core
---Core.js
---Something.js
---0_Header.js
--FileLoader
---ExternalInterface.js
---Core.js
---Helper.js
```

Необходимо чтобы **concat** собирал примерно вот так:

```
build
-js
--Ext
---Core
----Core.min.js
---FileLoader
----FileLoader.min.js
```

Здесь подошло бы что-то вроде этого:

```
concat: {
  ***
  files: {
    'build/js/Ext/$1/$1.min.js': ['src/js/(*)/**/*.js']
  }
  ***
}
```

Но это не работает. Отдельно прописывать каждый модуль, когда явно можно автоматизировать - глупо.
Как правильно прописать? Благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант - сформировать нужный объект руками:

```
var files = {};
grunt.file.expand("./src/js/*").forEach(function (dir) {
    var dirname = dir.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
    files['build/js/Ext/' + dirname + '.min.js'] = ['src/js/' + dirname + '/**/*.js'];
});
```

И использовать в конфигурации для concat:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    concat: {
        dist: {
            files: files
        }
    }
});
```

Альтернатива - использовать возможность переименовать dst (регулярка на скорую руку, не учитывает backslah-и):

```
grunt.initConfig({
    concat: {
        dist: {
            files:[{
                expand: true,
                src: ['src/js/**/*.js'],
                rename: function (dst, src) {
                    return src.replace(/src\/js\/([^\/]*).*/, 'build/js/Ext/$1/$1.min.js');
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Идея хороша, но отдельно обыскать пути легко, а есть ли в `grunt` адекватные нативные средства (вроде обратных ссылок как в регулярках или подобное) - это как раз и вопрос. Но +1 :)

Comment: Возможно какой-то из плагинов делает это. В ядре вроде бы нет такой возможности (используется minimatch/node-glob). Можно feature request попробовать в [grunt-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat/issues).

Comment: Ну уже что-то :) Благодарю.